# In Powershell can i use the select-string -quiet switch within a foreach statement

Tags: powershell, select-string

i am trying to write a script to check if a string is within a file, if it is then carry on and check the next one and continue until all are checked, if it finds one that is not present then the script will terminate. Am i able to use a `select-string` statement with a boolean outcome (`-quiet` switch) within an if statement. The `pinglist.txt` file contains a list of servers and the other `_pinglist.ini` contains a large list of servers.I am new to this so please excuse my poor scripting. Thanks

```
$Original_File = 'C:\Jobs\Powershell\Pinger\Other_PingList.ini'

$PingList= 'C:\Jobs\Powershell\pinglist.txt'

#

Foreach ($item in $pingList)

{If (Select-String $Original_File -pattern $item -quiet) {

Write-Host "Servers Present In File - Carrying on"

}}
Else {

   Write-Host "Servers Not Present In File - Terminating"

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a try

```
$Original_File = gc 'C:\Jobs\Powershell\Pinger\Other_PingList.ini'
$PingList= gc 'C:\Jobs\Powershell\pinglist.txt'    

Foreach ($item in $pingList)
{
    If ($Original_File -match $item ) 
    {
        Write-Host "Servers $item Present In File - Carrying on"
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "Servers $item Not Present In File - Terminating"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, i tried that and received the following error, Bad argument to operator '-match': parsing "C:\Jobs\Powershell\pinglist.txt" - Unrecognized escape sequence \J..
At line:11 char:30
+     If ($Original_File -match <<<<  $item ) 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument

Comment: @Mach1 look @ the `gc` (alias for get-content cmdlet) in the variable declaration... I think you missed it! Copy&Paste all my code...

Comment: @Mach1 Make sure you mark an answer as "Accepted" if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Am i able to use a select-string statement with a boolean outcome (-quiet switch) within an if statement

Yes. From the documentation:

> -Quiet
>
> Returns a Boolean value (true or false), instead of a MatchInfo object. The value is "true" if the pattern is found; otherwise, the value is "false".

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx)

Are you having an issue with your current script? What prompted this question to begin with?

Comment: Hi, yes, it was throwing an error out.  parsing "C:\Jobs\Powershell\pinglist.txt" - Unrecognized escape sequence \J.
At line:9 char:19
+ {If (Select-String <<<<  $Original_File -pattern $item -quiet) {
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Select-String], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand

Comment: @Mach1 Could be that your `Foreach` block doesn't include your `Else`. You should move the extra bracket on the line after `Write-Host` to the far side of the `Else`. That way, both the `If` and `Else` are contained within the `Foreach`

Comment: @Mach1 and @C.B. had a good suggestion as well, you need to use `$Original_File = Get-Content "...."`,