# Use PowerShell's type -wait with select-string to Real-Time Monitor an Application Log for a Condition and Execute an Action (like tail -f or watch)

Tags: powershell, scripting, watch, tail, select-string

I am trying to use PowerShell's `type -wait` command to monitor a log file in real time on Windows in the same way that I would use `tail -f` on Linux, and I want to pipe the file to another command - `select-string`, like `grep` - that will trigger an action based on a condition. On Linux, I would use `watch` to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

In the following example, I am trying to print the phrase `"You caught a critter!"` whenever a new line, which contains the string `"status=Caught"`, is written to the log file.

```
while (1) {if (type -wait "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\CritterCatcherApp\Logs\CritterBag-170118.log" | select-string -quiet "state=Caught") {write-host "You caught a critter!"} else {continue}}
```

Please note that the `-quiet` argument for the `select-string` command returns `True`. Actually, in this example, it only returns `True` one time, when I first run the command, as the log file has existing lines that contain the string `"status=Caught"`.

I do need to somehow overlook the existing strings (or, e.g., rotate the log files), but right now, the issue is that I need the PowerShell script to not only continue to tail the file, but I also need it to continue to evaluate whether each new line that is written to the file contains the given string. Then, if the string is present, I need to execute an arbitrary action, like print a line; else, continue listening for the string.

The following post indicates that the `-wait` argument is an option for the `Get-Content` cmdlet: [How to monitor a windows log file in real time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1845/how-to-monitor-a-windows-log-file-in-real-time#comment52128_64129)  . I am not sure if I should expect `-wait` to work with a `foreach` loop, as described in this post: [In Powershell can i use the select-string -quiet switch within a foreach statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18918135/5100006) .

How can I modify the above PowerShell script to tail a log file and execute an action for each new line with a given string, and continue to tail the file and evaluate new lines as they are written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it on the pipeline with `Where-Object (?)` and `ForEach-Object (%)`:

```
Get-Content file -wait | ? { $_ -match "status=Caught" } | % { Write-Host "You caught a critter!" }
```

Each time `status=Caught` is detected in the file, the `Write-Host` in the `ForEach-Object` will execute

Comment: You got it - It works. This is for sure the answer, and at one total line of code, it is an elegant solution. I get the `Write-Host` output a few times due to the existing entries in the file, and solving that will be the next step that I take. Thank you.

Comment: @RockyRaccoon I know this is old, but have you solved the next step? I.e. skipping lines already present in the file before you start monitoring?

Comment: @AleksG If I recall correctly, I made the `match` criteria more specific, and the log file that I was targeting did rotate each day, with the file name reflecting the current date. So in combination, I was able to avoid any extra lines, if not actually skip them. A quick search turns up the PowerShell `Select-Object` cmdlet, which has a `-Skip` parameter, but I did not use it. I no longer have access to the script, or else I would tell you for certain what I did. If you post a question with your requirements, I will take a look at it.